# How to sum overlapping timeframes across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple tables with multiple timeframes that I need to calculate the overlapping times when all tables overlap, but not otherwise.

In the below example, I would only need to sum time for the timeframes with borders:

[image]

Cannot just use basic theta joins since A is not always < or > X, etc.

Example table:

```
PLACE 1 PLACE 1 TIME IN     PLACE 1 TIME OUT    PLACE 2 PLACE 2 TIME IN     PLACE 2 TIME OUT    PLACE 3 PLACE 3 TIME IN     PLACE 3 TIME OUT
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:24:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 11:04:00.000 2013-05-09 12:16:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:24:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 08:49:00.000 2013-05-09 09:36:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:24:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 07:52:00.000 2013-05-09 08:21:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:24:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 09:57:00.000 2013-05-09 10:39:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 15:06:00.000 2013-05-09 15:39:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 11:04:00.000 2013-05-09 12:16:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 15:06:00.000 2013-05-09 15:39:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 08:49:00.000 2013-05-09 09:36:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 15:06:00.000 2013-05-09 15:39:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 07:52:00.000 2013-05-09 08:21:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 15:06:00.000 2013-05-09 15:39:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 09:57:00.000 2013-05-09 10:39:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 11:22:00.000 2013-05-09 12:31:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 11:04:00.000 2013-05-09 12:16:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 11:22:00.000 2013-05-09 12:31:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 08:49:00.000 2013-05-09 09:36:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 11:22:00.000 2013-05-09 12:31:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 07:52:00.000 2013-05-09 08:21:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 11:22:00.000 2013-05-09 12:31:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 09:57:00.000 2013-05-09 10:39:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 12:52:00.000 2013-05-09 14:35:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 11:04:00.000 2013-05-09 12:16:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 08:54:00.000 2013-05-09 11:02:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 11:04:00.000 2013-05-09 12:16:00.000
3929    2013-05-09 07:06:00.000 2013-05-09 08:29:00.000 3930    2013-05-09 12:52:00.000 2013-05-09 14:35:00.000 3931    2013-05-09 08:49:00.000 2013-05-09 09:36:00.000
```

Comment: Post actual/sample data, as text please. That image is far from what your actual data looks like making it impossible for us to answer I'm afraid.

Comment: The general idea wiill be to make a table with all possible times, create the period between each time and the next, and then count where between. At any rate, we need to know your tables and data.

Comment: Tried adding example data; bear with me on formatting, 1st post here. :)

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: you are still shrouding your code in mystery, so I cannot help much. You can use option (maxrecursion 0) at end of query in order to avoid the recursion limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a two-step process.   First you want to find the rows that do have overlapping rows in the other tables.

The age-old technique for finding overlap between two ranges is that an overlap can only exist if the beginning of range A is not after the end of range B, AND the end of range A is not before the beginning of range B.

In other words, if B starts before A ends, and B also ends after A starts, then there is an overlap.

Now how to express this in SQL:  You start with a "root" table as the first table in the FROM clause.   Let's call it Table1 with the columns A & B (going from your image).

To find rows in the other two tables that have any overlap, JOIN like this:

```
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t2.E <= t1.B AND t2.F >= t1.A
INNER JOIN Table3 t3  --this table has to overlap both of the others
  ON t3.X <= t1.B AND t3.Y >= t1.A
  AND t3.X <= t2.F AND t3.Y >= t2.E
```

By using INNER JOINs, all rows that don't have overlaps in all three tables are eliminated from consideration.

Then to return just the periods that overlap, get the MAX of `t1.A, t2.E, t3.X` as the beginning of the overlap, and the MIN of `t1.B, t2.F, t3.Y` as the end of the overlap.

Comment: This doesn't work if T2.E is >= T1.A and/or T2.F is <= T1.B, which could still indicate overlap.

Comment: Yes it does.  If T2.E < T1.B, then it doesn't matter whether it's <=> T1.A, as long as the other condition (T2.F >= T1.A) is also true.    Draw it out, you'll see.

Comment: @TabAlleman This solution looks good when you know how many tables you want to join, we have a case where all the data is in one result set (opening hours) so we need a recursive (CTE) solution which iterates all possible overlaps. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't really picture what you're describing @Wartodust, you should post a question so you can illustrate with an example.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have created a new post with my question and working examples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847837/how-to-retrieve-overlapping-timeframes-from-a-single-table-with-multiple-time-sp