# Two tables with time select none overlapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two able with timeslots first one When a person is booked second table is timeslots where a task can be done.

I need to find all time where a task can be done and by who.

Table a is The list of time where the person is booked.

Table b is a list of all time slots where  a task can be cross join be list who can do the task

```
table a
2019-03-28 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-03-28 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-29 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-03-29 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-03-30 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-03-31 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-04-01 07:00:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-04-01 13:00:00.0000000 | 2019-04-01 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-04-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-04-02 07:00:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-04-02 13:00:00.0000000 | 2019-04-02 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-04-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-04-03 07:00:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-04-03 19:00:00.0000000 | 2019-04-03 23:59:00.0000000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6


table b
2019-03-29 18:00:00.000 | 2019-03-29 20:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-29 19:00:00.000 | 2019-03-29 21:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-29 20:00:00.000 | 2019-03-29 22:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-29 21:00:00.000 | 2019-03-29 23:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-29 22:00:00.000 | 2019-03-30 00:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-29 23:00:00.000 | 2019-03-30 01:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-30 00:00:00.000 | 2019-03-30 02:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-30 03:00:00.000 | 2019-03-30 05:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-30 04:00:00.000 | 2019-03-30 06:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6
2019-03-30 05:00:00.000 | 2019-03-30 07:00:00.000 | C235E2D9-F1C8-4D04-BA71-097BE66135E6

DECLARE @BookedTimeslot TABLE (

    [StartTime] datetime2(7),

    [EndTime] datetime2(7),
    [StakeholderId] uniqueidentifier

)

DECLARE @PossibleTimeslot TABLE (

    [StartTime] datetime2(7),

    [EndTime] datetime2(7),
    [StakeholderId] uniqueidentifier

)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am using Azure MS SQL

Comment: It will help (especially with code samples!) if you list table structures, even if just `Table_A  Id  StartTime  EndTime`.

Comment: @user2438077 What have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: Wow I basically just answered this question (except with the reverse goal):   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400778/1507566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want rows in B that where there is no A record that overlaps the B timespan for a matching person (ID).

```
SELECT b.StartTime, b.EndTime, b.StakeholderID
FROM TableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM TableA a 
  WHERE b.StakeholderID=a.StakeholderID
  AND (a.StartTime<b.EndTime AND a.EndTime>b.StartTime))
```