# How to retrieve overlapping timeframes from a single table with multiple time spans?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This topic is similar as this post but my results all come from the same result set.
[How to sum overlapping timeframes across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399922/how-to-sum-overlapping-timeframes-across-multiple-tables)

I have a result set with multiple openinghours for different services which do or do not overlap.
Based on that result set I want to calculate which openinghours do fit and match for all results of that day.
The result set is variable, so multiple services are possible with multiple openinghours on the same day.
All services need to fit, otherwise no results expected.

[image]

Example result set for 3 services which have 4 possible openinghours:

```
declare @source table(
    id int not null,
    serviceId int not null,
    startDate datetime, 
    endDate datetime,
    [date] date
)

insert into @source values (1, 4, '2020-03-16 07:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 10:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
insert into @source values (2, 4, '2020-03-16 11:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 16:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
insert into @source values (3, 4426, '2020-03-16 08:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 16:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
insert into @source values (4, 91, '2020-03-16 15:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 17:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')

 select 
        id
    ,   serviceId
    ,   startDate
    ,   endDate
    ,   [date]

from @source
```

Expected result:

```
2020-03-16 15:00:00.000 - 2020-03-16 16:00:00.000
```

Example result set for 1 service which has 2 possible openinghours:

```
declare @source table(
    id int not null,
    serviceId int not null,
    startDate datetime, 
    endDate datetime,
    [date] date
)

insert into @source values (1, 4, '2020-03-16 07:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 10:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
insert into @source values (2, 4, '2020-03-16 11:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 16:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')

select 
        id
    ,   serviceId
    ,   startDate
    ,   endDate
    ,   [date]
from @source
```

Expected result:

```
2020-03-16 07:00:00.000 - 2020-03-16 10:00:00.000
2020-03-16 11:00:00.000 - 2020-03-16 16:00:00.000
```

Since the result set is variable, I think I need a recursive **Common Table Expression** which iterates the result set till no more possible values are returned.
I did not find a way yet to find a solution which works in all scenario's, this is my attempt:

```
declare @source table(
    id int not null,
    serviceId int not null,
    startDate datetime, 
    endDate datetime,
    [date] date
)

insert into @source values (1, 4, '2020-03-16 07:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 10:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
insert into @source values (2, 4, '2020-03-16 11:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 16:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
----Uncommenting causes no results, which is wrong
--insert into @source values (3, 4426, '2020-03-16 08:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 16:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')
--insert into @source values (4, 91, '2020-03-16 15:00:00.000', '2020-03-16 17:00:00.000', '2020-03-16')

select 
        openinghours.[date]
    ,   openinghours.[from] as [from]
    ,   openinghours.[to] as [to]
from
(
    select 
            openinghours_with_comparison.[date]
        ,   openinghours_with_comparison.[from1]
        ,   openinghours_with_comparison.[to1]
        ,   max(openinghours_with_comparison.[has_overlap]) as overlap
        ,   case 
                when max(openinghours_with_comparison.[has_overlap]) = 1 then max(openinghours_with_comparison.[new_from])
                else openinghours_with_comparison.[from1]
            end as [from]
        ,   case 
                when max(openinghours_with_comparison.[has_overlap]) = 1 then min(openinghours_with_comparison.[new_to])
                else openinghours_with_comparison.[to1]
            end as [to]
    from
    (
        select 
                openinghours.[date]
            ,   openinghours.[serviceId]
            ,   openinghours_to_compare.[serviceId] as [compare_service_id]
            ,   openinghours.[startDate] as [from1]
            ,   openinghours.[endDate] as [to1]
            ,   openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] as [from2]
            ,   openinghours_to_compare.[endDate] as [to2]
            ,   case
                    when 
                        openinghours.[serviceId] != openinghours_to_compare.[serviceId] and
                        (
                            (
                                openinghours.[startDate] != openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] 
                                and 
                                (
                                    openinghours.[startDate] between openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] and openinghours_to_compare.[endDate] 
                                    or
                                    openinghours.[endDate] between openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] and openinghours_to_compare.[endDate]
                                )
                            )or
                            (
                                openinghours.[endDate] != openinghours_to_compare.[endDate]
                                and
                                (
                                    openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] between openinghours.[startDate] and openinghours.[endDate] 
                                    or
                                    openinghours_to_compare.[endDate] between openinghours.[startDate] and openinghours.[endDate]
                                )
                            )
                        ) then 1
                    else 0
                end as [has_overlap]
            ,   case
                    when (openinghours.[startDate] != openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] and openinghours.[startDate] between openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] and openinghours_to_compare.[endDate]) then openinghours.[startDate]
                    else openinghours_to_compare.[startDate]
                end as [new_from]
            ,   case
                    when (openinghours.[endDate] != openinghours_to_compare.[endDate] and openinghours.[endDate] between openinghours_to_compare.[startDate] and openinghours_to_compare.[endDate]) then openinghours.[endDate]
                    else openinghours_to_compare.[endDate]
                end as [new_to]
        from
        (
            select 
                *
            from @source
        ) openinghours
        left join
        (
            select 
                *
            from @source
        )openinghours_to_compare on openinghours_to_compare.[date] = openinghours.[date]
)openinghours_with_comparison
    group by 
            openinghours_with_comparison.[date]
        ,   openinghours_with_comparison.[serviceId]
        ,   openinghours_with_comparison.[from1]
        ,   openinghours_with_comparison.[to1]
)openinghours
group by 
        openinghours.[date]
    ,   openinghours.[from]
    ,   openinghours.[to]
having count(*) = (select count(distinct serviceId) from @source)
and openinghours.[from] <= openinghours.[to]
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying DDL and DML, however, the table you define (`@source`) has 4 columns, but you then `INSERT` 5 columns. Are we missing something?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for mentioning that, I have updated it.